# Renombrar un archivo en Python con nombre variable

Tags: python, string

Pls. your help, estoy intentando crear una descarga automática en Python de un sistema web de la empresa en que trabajo, pero los archivos bajan siempre con el mismo nombre, y lo que necesito es que cuando descargue el archivo numero 2, le agregue la fecha y hora actual al nombre original y asi con los que le siguen, de modo que cada archivo sea único, es posible? obviamente asi como lo dejé, me dice que el archivo ya existe y se detiene el proceso :(

```
shutil.move("C://Users//xxx//Downloads//FormWiseReport.xls", "C://Users//xxx//OneDrive-xxx//Credit Projects")**
```

---

---

Error: Destination path 'C://Users//xxx//OneDrive - xxx//Credit Projects\FormWiseReport.xls' already exists``

gracias por su tiempo

Comment: ¿Has usado el mismo nombre de archivo en múltiples ocasiones? Podrías verificar si existe un archivo con el nombre destino primero con `os.path.exists`

Comment: Sí, claro que es posible. Qué has intentado hasta ahora para añadir la fecha y hora?

Comment: ¿Has usado el mismo nombre de archivo en múltiples ocasiones? Podrías verificar si existe un archivo con el nombre destino primero con os.path.exists – 
Jacobo  hace 14 horas Hola Jacobo, gracias por responder, si el archivo se descarga automaticamente con el mismo nombre siempre, usualmente ponemos a mano el dia y la hora como parte de su nombre para identificarlo, pero intento que esa parte se haga automatica...

Comment: í, claro que es posible. Qué has intentado hasta ahora para añadir la fecha y hora? – 
César González
 Hola Cesar gracais por responder, no tengo mucha experiencia y no encontré mucha ayuda en la web :(, el archivo se descarga automaticamente en downloads, y luego lo muevo a una carpeta de red en one drive, la primera vez funciona genial, luego obviamente me avisa que el archivo ya existe en el destino.

Comment: Ok pero... Sabes cómo trabajar con strings al menos? Lo que necesitas es simplemente modificar el string con el path de destino para añadir la fecha y hora. Has intentado construir la cadena con la fecha y hora?

Comment: Ok pero... Sabes cómo trabajar con strings al menos? Lo que necesitas es simplemente modificar el string con el path de destino para añadir la fecha y hora. Has intentado construir la cadena con la fecha y hora? – 
César González   Esto es lo que usé:  file_oldname = os.path.join("C://Users//xxx//OneDrive - yyy//Credit Projects//FormWiseReport.xls")
file_newname = os.path.join("C://Users//xxx//OneDrive - yyy//Credit Projects//, f"{file_oldname}_{str(datetime.datetime.now())}.xlsx")
os.rename(file_oldname, file_newname)            SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 2)

Comment: Ese error lo único que te dice es que tienes un string sin cerrar en la línea 2. Voy a añadirte una respuesta con una forma de hacer lo que necesitas pero te recomiendo que hagas alguna formación para entender cómo trabajar con strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una pequeña función para hacer lo que necesitas:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime


def rename_file_to_now(filename):
    splitted = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fecha = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S')
    new_filename = f'{splitted[0]} {fecha}{splitted[1]}'
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

O más comprimido:

```
def rename_file_to_now(f):
    os.rename(f, f'{os.path.splitext(f)[0]} {datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")}{os.path.splitext(f)[1]}')
```

La variable `splitted` obtiene de `os.path.splitext` una tupla con dos valores: la ruta del archivo **sin extensión** y la extensión (con el delimitador incluído).

`fecha` es un string construido a partir de la fecha actual con el formato '%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S'. Hacerlo como planteas en los comentarios va a incluir caracteres como : y . en la ruta final del archivo que pueden darte algún dolor de cabeza.

`new_filename` simplemente concatena las tres partes.

Con `os.rename` ejecutamos el renombrado.

Tal como te digo en mi último comentario: te recomiendo que hagas alguna formación básica para entender las bases de manipulación de cadenas de texto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, seguro, ese es uno de los puntos que tengo para seguir aprendiendo, muchas gracias por tu tiempo Cesar, abrazo.

Comment: De nada, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como válida y agradecer puntuándola